# Is it possible to repeat a method in a for loop?

Tags: python

so I am writing a code to find the height of a binary search tree. My first thoughts were to traverse through both the right and left subtrees, append the values of the nodes in each subtree to a list, and then get the length of the list, and the longer list would be the height of the tree. Here is my code:

```
def getHeight(self,root):
    
lstr = []
    
lstl = []

    if root.right is not None:
        lstr.append(root.right.data)
    if root.right.right is not None:
            lstr.append(root.right.right.data)
    
            
        
    if not root.left == None:
        lstl.append(root.left.data)
    if root.left.left is not None:
            lstr.append(root.left.left.data)
        
    return lstr
    return lstl
```

However, is it possible to use a for loop to keep iterating through the .right.right.right and just continue using the .right attribute in the if statement until the for loop ends?

Comment: What you are looking for is recursion. So `if root.right.right is not None:` you need to call `getHeight` again.

Comment: Take a look at [Height of a Binary Tree (Python Code with example)](https://favtutor.com/blogs/binary-tree-height) which is a tutorial on the two standard methods.